# Load data infile MySQL with absolute URL

Tags: mysql, csv

i trying load a CSV in a table.
I have my CSV in a folder of my server. (wwww.myweb.com/temp/file.csv)

I use this sentence:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'http://wwww.myweb.com/temp/file.csv' INTO TABLE ga_tmpActivosDocumentos FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (idTipoSuelo,C_Latitud,C_Longitud,Referencia,Zona,idProvincia,Poblacion,TituloActivo,Descripcion,Superficie,Gastos,Equipamiento,EquipamientoEN,GestionDocumental,PrecioVenta,CampoLibre1_Texto,CampoLibre1_Titulo,CampoLibre1_TextoEN,CampoLibre1_TituloEN,Activo, IMG1,IMG_Desc1,IMG_Desc1EN,IMG2,IMG_Desc2,IMG_Desc2EN,IMG3,IMG_Desc3,IMG_Desc3EN,IMG4,IMG_Desc4,IMG_Desc4EN,DOC1,DOC_Desc1,DOC_Desc1EN,DOC2,DOC_Desc2,DOC_Desc2EN,DOC3,DOC_Desc3,DOC_Desc3EN,DOC4,DOC_Desc4,DOC_Desc4EN,URL1,URL_Desc1,URL_Desc1EN,URL2,URL_Desc2,URL_Desc2EN) SET idCliente = 23
```

The sentence not work for me. I try to change the path to .../temp/file.csv, and other combinations but not work.

Also use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" but does not work.

I have read other topics, but only look examples with a relative URL, never absolute.

Thanks, and sorry for my english

Comment: *"MySQL can't download the file for you. You'll have to download the file first (using a tool like wget), and specify the filename you downloaded it as.

You'll also need to change "LOAD DATA INFILE" to "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE". The reasons for needing that are kind of technical, but have to do with your database server not being the same as your web server."* - As per https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-130247-post-137985.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will continue trying to find the error.

Answer (score 3):

@vadym-tyemirov answer works but if you don't want to create a temporary file, one solution is to load it from '/dev/stdin' and pipe it to the mysql cli:

```sh
wget -O - 'http://wwww.myweb.com/temp/file.csv' |
    mysql \
        --user=root \
        --password=password \
        --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dev/stdin' INTO TABLE table_name"
```

Comment: Will this work even if the file is enormous? Let's say, a few gigabytes?

Answer (score 2):

1. Save CSV file on your LOCAL computer.
2. Connect to the DB from your LOCAL computer
3. Issue the following command: `load data LOCAL infile '/tmp/file.csv' INTO TABLE table_name;`

[You can also load data files by using the mysqlimport utility; it operates by sending a LOAD DATA INFILE statement to the server. The --local option causes mysqlimport to read data files from the client host.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL cannot access the file in that location.  Try moving it somewhere simple like /tmp (or copy it) on the local filesystem, and not via a URL parameter.

The MySQL process likely cannot load the folders BEFORE "temp/file.csv"

Comment: Thanks for the response, finds all the options, and will post the solution if I give her.